# No such property: org.codehaus.grails.INCLUDED_JS_LIBRARIES

Tags: spring, tomcat, grails, phantomjs, grails-2.2

#### The requirement

I'm trying to run my JavaScript tests in a custom test phase based in the functional test phase. Basically it needs to:

- Startup embedded Tomcat
- Open a controller
- Check the result of the executed tests

#### What I've done

First, I created my custom test phase, based on this [post](http://ldaley.com/post/615966534/custom-grails-test). So my _Events.groovy looks like

```
includeTargets << new File("${basedir}/scripts/_RunJavaScriptUiTests.groovy")

eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
  tomcat.connector.setAttribute("compression", "on")
  tomcat.connector.setAttribute("compressableMimeType", "text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript")
  tomcat.connector.port = serverPort
}

eventAllTestsStart = {
  phasesToRun << "uijs"
}

uijsTests = ["uijs"]

uijsTestPhasePreparation = { 
  functionalTestPhasePreparation()
}

uijsTestPhaseCleanUp = { 
  functionalTestPhaseCleanUp()
}
eventTestPhaseEnd = { phase ->
  if( phase == "uijs" ) {
    runJavaScriptUiTests()
  }
}
```

Next, I decided to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to open my page and analyze the executed tests. So I used this in the *RunJavaScriptUiTests.groovy* script

```
target(runJavaScriptUiTests:"Running Siesta tests") {

    event("StatusUpdate", ["Siesta test phase..."])

    //this is the script that evaluates the result of the tests
    File script = new File("web-app/js/siesta/siesta-phantomjs-runner.js")

    String home = System.getenv("PHANTOMJS_HOME")
    if(!home) {
        throw new RuntimeException("PHANTOMJS_HOME must be set.")
    }

    String executable = "${home}bin${File.separator}phantomjs"
    String port = System.getProperty("server.port","8080")
    String url = "http://localhost:$port/insoft-ext-ui/siesta" //url of my tests

    println "Running Phantomjs ${executable} ${script.absolutePath} "

    try {
        ant.exec(executable: executable, outputproperty: "cmdOut", failonerror: 'true', errorproperty: "cmdErr") {
            arg(value: script.absolutePath)
            arg(value: url)
        }
        }catch(e) {
        println "ERROR: $e"
        throw e
    }

    try {

        String output = "${ant.project.properties.cmdOut}"
        println output

        }catch(e) {
        event("StatusError",["Exception $e"])
    }

}
```

I can see that the *functionalTestPhasePreparation* runs, because this starts up my application correctly. I can also see that the phantomjs command is correct, when it prints:

```
Running: /desenv/phantomjs-1.9.2/bin/phantomjs /desenv/java/projetos/insoft-ext-ui/web-app/js/siesta/siesta-phantomjs-runner.js http://localhost:8080/insoft-ext-ui/siesta
```

But this gives me the *groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException*

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org.codehaus.grails.INCLUDED_JS_LIBRARIES for class: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:273)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.JavascriptLibraryFilters$_closure1_closure2_closure3.doCall(JavascriptLibraryFilters.groovy:27)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.JavascriptLibraryFilters$_closure1_closure2_closure3.doCall(JavascriptLibraryFilters.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

For full Stacktrace see [here](https://gist.github.com/sergiomichels/6630172).

The interesting is that if I just do

```
grails test run-app
phantomjs /desenv/java/projetos/insoft-ext-ui/web-app/js/siesta/siesta-phantomjs-runner.js http://localhost:8080/insoft-ext-ui/siesta
```

The script works and I don't get any exception.

#### The question

Why MissingPropertyException is thrown? I looked at *JavascriptLibraryFilters* and didn't find a reason for it.

**EDIT**

#### About the Tomcat

I'm using the embedded Tomcat that comes with Grails, but enabling compressing in the _Events.groovy:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
    tomcat.connector.setAttribute("compression", "on")
    tomcat.connector.setAttribute("compressableMimeType", "text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript")
    tomcat.connector.port = serverPort
}
```

Comment: Any updates on your situation?

Comment: I missed your answer (don't know why)! I will take a look at this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a direct solution, but I can help you research this.

The source of your problem is apparently `org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`, which is applied in your Tomcat environment, which explains why your code works standalone.

Other issues which refer to this same Spring class exist on Stack Overflow.  Most of them are problems regarding incorrect multi-part request processing.  **This would lead me to believe PhantomJS is making multi-part calls without the appropriate casting or interfaces for your environment.**  I suspect a change to either your Tomcat or Grails configuration may be required.

Here are several of the SO questions to which I refer:

- SO: [Uploading file throws No signature of method exception (in getFile() method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259264/uploading-file-throws-no-signature-of-method-exception-in-getfile-method)
- SO: [uploading a file in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439135/uploading-a-file-in-grails)
- SO: [Communication between Signed Applet and server side Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758583/communication-between-signed-applet-and-server-side-controller)
- SO: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Standard argument type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308824/java-lang-illegalstateexception-standard-argument-type-org-springframework-web)

Here is a potentially relevant bug on Grails / CXF:

- [Spring Security bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-191), referring to a [CXF bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCXF-5), which says *"To enable MTOM on CXF you have to disable Grails' multipart handling by setting the option `grails.web.disable.multipart=true` in `Config.groovy`"*

Please provide any details regarding your Tomcat / Grails settings and/or confirm that you have investigated these potential issue paths so that we may discount them.

Hopefully this answer points you or others in the right direction for a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately I'm not working with file upload, so I don't need a multipart request in this case. It's just a normal controller that renders a view, but you have a good argument: probably PhantomJS makes some different call in this case.

Comment: @SérgioMichels - you might not be working with upload directly, but PhantomJS might be attempting some sort of multi-part and have the wrong configuration parameter set.

Comment: Yeah you have a point :-) I'm using the embedded Tomcat of Grails 2.2.4, and don't have the grails.web.disable.multipart configured.